# Estrutura JSON para HighChart Line

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, highcharts

Gostaria de saber qual seria a estrutura correta para criar um gráfico LINE no HighCharts com dados dinâmicos: Exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/gumaro/6u4Ha/2/


Eu possuo valores que quero mostrar em uma linha, a sua evolução durante os meses, porém não tenho todos os meses preenchidos e dessa forma o gráfico começaria na metade do ano (por exemplo).

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer o JSON para preencher o eixo X com os meses referentes juntamente com os valores?

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes? Poderia postar alguma tentativa que já tenha feito?

Comment: Não sei se entendi de fato o que você quer como resposta. 
Se estiver falando do formato do JSON, pode fazer algo parecido com o abaixo:
`{"Result":[["Maio", "Junho", "Julho"], [20, 30, 15]]}`

Depois quando for usar faça:

`Result[0] //X`
`Result[1] //Y`

Se não for isso que deseja, comente mais detalhes ai pra ficar mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: @ErlonCharles Não sei se isso ajuda: http://pastebin.com/5yM4uFNL

Comment: @RenattoMachado Dessa forma eu não precisaria colocar valores em "Series"?

Comment: @gumaro Precisa sim. Só vai substituir a chamada:
`categories: Result[0];` **E** `series: Result[1]`

Comment: Já tentou usar [DxChartJs](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/SalesViewer)?
Nele você passa apenas um dataSource com um JSON muito simples, dai ele já monta tanto o X quanto o Y.

Comment: @RenattoMachado: estou utilizando o HighCharts em um trabalho de conclusão e pelo que vi no DxChartJs é somente 30 dias de testes, correto?

Comment: @gumaro Infelizmente a versão trial é só 30 dias mesmo. Você pode usar o [CharJs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) é bem parecido com a estrutura que te falei e é `OpenSource`! São apenas sugestões, o `HighCharts` também é muito bom!

Comment: @RenattoMachado pois é, fica complicado com versão trial. O ChartJS eu já utilizei em um outro projeto que fiz, optei pelo HighCharts por causa das funcionalidade de exportação e sua velocidade de carregamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi de fato o que você quer como resposta. Se estiver falando do formato do JSON, pode fazer algo parecido com o abaixo:

`{"Result":[["Maio", "Junho", "Julho"], [20, 30, 15]]}`

**Depois quando for usar faça:**

`categories: Result[0];`

**E**

`series: Result[1]`